# Performance Impact of Application Packaging in WebLogic 8.1 SP6- EAR vs WAR

Tags: java, performance, weblogic, packaging

We have run into a strange situation.

We recently moved all components of an EAR into a WAR - without changing underlying Weblogic version (8.1 SP6). Immediately after the repackaging, we observed **significantly** higher CPU utilization on the servers. We have run several tests and based on results so far, our current theory is that differences in inclusion of libraries (APP-INF/lib in EAR & WEB-INF/lib in WAR) is causing this issue.

Anyone else have any experience/war stories/thoughts on trouble-shooting this?

Thanks!

Comment: Never heard of that. Were you playing with the classloader in the EAR?

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming you moved all classes from a single EAR to a single WAR and not distributed stuff across WARs?  You should profile the app and check the thread dumps at high CPU to see what's happening. And whether setting prefer-web-inf-classes to true in weblogic.xml makes any diff?

Comment: @josek `prefer-web-inf-classes` requires an EAR packaging AFAIK

Comment: @Pascal, i rechecked that we have used prefer-web-inf-classes for a standalone war. So also does the Grails war as here http://www.grails.org/Deployment/

Comment: @josek - Thanks for the suggestion. Will try out prefer-web-inf-classes to true and let you know if that made a difference.

Comment: @josek We tried setting prefer-web-inf-classes to true but it didn't help. Now trying to see if we can move third-party libraries out of WEB-INF/lib to classpath....we really want to keep application as WAR if possible hence this effort.

Comment: Well, guessing is a pretty limited approach when it comes to performance management. Questions:

1. How has throughput changed with moving to WAR packaging?
2. Can you run your application under a profiler (my preference is JProfiler)? Where does it spend CPU?
3. What is the result of comparison of profiling sessions for EAR and WAR packaging?